# How is the dividend payment calculated when an asset is disposed on the ex date?

Tags: calculation, dividends, financial-literacy, ex-dividend-date

Example:

```
XYZ Corp pays a $0.25/share dividend - Ex date=1/15/13, Pay date 1/31/2013
I own 100 total shares of XYZ on 1/1/2013
I buy 50 shares of XYZ on 1/15/2013 at 12 PM (increasing shares to 150)
I buy 50 mor shares of XYZ on 1/15/2013 at 12 PM (increasing shares to 200)
I dispose of all 200 shares of XYZ by 4PM on 1/15/2013
```

On 1/31/2013, what is my dividend payment worth?

- 25.00 (balance on **start** of *ex date*:1/15/2013)
- 37.50 / 50.00 (balances **during** *ex date*:1/15/2013)
- Nothing (because I didn't own it at the end of *ex date*: 1/15/2013)
- Something else entirely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must own the shares prior to the ex-dividend date. Whatever you buy or sell on or after the ex-dividend day you will not receive dividends for.

So you would get $25 in dividends based on the 100 shares you owned before the ex-dividend date.